# CKFinder 3 Returning Wrong URLs for Selected Files

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ckfinder

I've encountered a strange problem while integrating the ASP.NET version of CKFinder 3 on my site. I'm creating a modal instance to select a file to populate the value of a field but, instead of the expected URL of "/uploads/images/path/to/image.ext" using [`getUrl()`](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3/#!/api/CKFinder.Models.File-method-getUrl) when the [`files:choose`](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3/#!/api/CKFinder.Application-event-files_choose) event is fired, I am instead getting the following URL returned to me and I can't, for the life of me, figure out why or how to fix it.

```
http://domain.tld/path/to/ckf/connector?command=Proxy&lang=en&type=Images&currentFolder=%2Fpath%2Fto%2F&hash=[hash]&fileName=image.ext`
```

If it's relevant, the `backend` info for my "uploads" directory in "Web.config" looks like this:

```
<backend name="default" adapter="local" useProxyCommand="true">
    <option name="root" value="../../../uploads" />
    <option name="baseUrl" value="/uploads/" />
</backend>
```

And then the JavaScript I'm using to create the modal instance and listen for the `files:choose` event goes like this (the field I'm trying to populate is the previous sibling of the button used to create the modal):

```
document.getElementById("openckf").addEventListener("click",function(){
    var field=this.previousSibling;
    CKFinder.modal({
        onInit:function(finder){
            finder.on("files:choose",function(event){
                field.value=event.data.files.first().getUrl();
            });
        }
    });
},0);
```

**UPDATE:** The same thing is also happening when I add CKFinder to CKEditor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use direct URL-s you need to disable the proxy command feature: simply set `useProxyCommand="false"` in backend configuration, or completely remove this attribute. This option defines whether links to files should be direct, or files should be served by connector.