# Clean Url for Ckfinder and Ckeditor

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-5, ckeditor, ckfinder

I am using ckfinder with ckeditor using the .net connector. The html src looks like this http://localhost:3261/ckfinder/connector?command=Proxy&lang=en&type=private&currentFolder=%2F&hash=acdcccfd691e0e3d1dd1a000c0cde24da987cd36&fileName=Desert.jpg" style="height:768px; width:1024px when an image is brought using ckfinder. Is there a way to store clean URL so it can point directly to the folder structure and domain that i want to ?

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37322925/ckfinder-3-returning-wrong-urls-for-selected-files/37325325#37325325).

Backed configuration docs might be useful too: http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-net/configuration.html#configuration_options_backends.